# Karatsuba implementation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, karatsuba

I am trying to implement Kartsuba's algorithm in C, I followed the [pseudo code on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Pseudocode), but the problem is I don't always get the correct result.

here is the implementation:

```
long long karatsuba(char* a,char* b){
    if (atoi(a)<10 || atoi(b)<10)
        return atoi(a)*atoi(b);
    int m = ((strlen(a)<strlen(b))?strlen(a):strlen(b))/2;

    char* high1 = slice(a,0,m);
    char* low1 = slice(a,m,strlen(a)-m);
    char* high2 = slice(b,0,m);
    char* low2 = slice(b,m,strlen(b)-m);
    
    
    long long z0 = karatsuba(low1,low2);
    long long z1 = karatsuba(add(low1,high1),add(low2,high2));
    long long z2 = karatsuba(high1,high2);
    
    free(low1);
    free(high1);
    free(low2);
    free(high2);    

    return (z2*pow(10,m*2))+((z1-z2-z0)*pow(10,m)) + z0;
}
```

this is the `slice` function, it is used to partition a number into 2:

```
char* slice(char* s,int a,int n){
    char* r = calloc(n+1,sizeof(char));
    strncpy(r,s+a,n);
    return r;
}
```

And this is the `add` function which is used to add 2 numbers:

```
char* add(char* a,char* b){
    char* r = calloc((strlen(a)>strlen(b)?strlen(a):strlen(b))+2,sizeof(char));
    sprintf(r,"%lld",atoi(a)+atoi(b));
    return r;
}
```

P.S: Just out of curiosity, I saw in many implementations the use of max
(size(num1),size(num2)) instead of min, is that ok and does it change anything?

Comment: "I don't always get the correct result" - what data do you feed in, what results do you expect and which ones are you actually getting?

Comment: the algorithm is used to multiply two numbers a and b in string format. e.g for a="1234" and b="5678" I get 6592652 while the result should be 7006652

Comment: You *tried* to follow the en.wikipedia pseudocode. For the "scaling" by `10 ^ m2` to be correct, which part returned by, say `split_at(num1, m2)` *has to* have length *m2*: the more or the less significant part? Re-read the paragraph [Basic step](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Basic_step).

Comment: It should be the least significant part, right? thank you for the answer I'll try and fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to **@greybeard**'s comment, apparently the problem was that I partitioned the numbers in a way that the most significant part has m digits, instead it should be the least significant part, so to fix it:

I changed this part:

```
char* high1 = slice(a,0,m);
char* low1 = slice(a,m,strlen(a)-m);
char* high2 = slice(b,0,m);
char* low2 = slice(b,m,strlen(b)-m);
```

to:

```
char* high1 = slice(a,0,strlen(a)-m);
char* low1 = slice(a,strlen(a)-m,m);
char* high2 = slice(b,0,strlen(b)-m);
char* low2 = slice(b,strlen(b)-m,m);
```